# What are more efficient alternatives to walking?

Tags: substitute-tool, efficiency, travel

What can you use to move at a faster pace more efficiently than regular walking (especially for longer distances, like going to school or work)?

I know that you can use bike, but usually it's illegal to use it on the pavement/sidewalk.

*Note: It must be something that can be used on the sidewalk*

Comment: This reminds me of advice given to me by my mother when I was younger.  "If you ever get tired of walking, you can always jog."  O.o

Comment: Let's see... Driving?

Comment: @J.Musser Definitely not on the pavement/sidewalk.

Comment: So use the road? My (possibly too subtle) point was, you didn't clarify in your question any of these things. Why must you stay on the sidewalk? Are you looking for only self-propelled means of transportation?

Comment: @J.Musser Without clarifying where to use, it would be too broad. With driving, there is no much choices other than obvious such as cars, motors/bikes/scooters,  it's slow (in rush hours in central city such as London) and expensive (fuel, parking and congestion charges).

Comment: In the United States ANY bicycle in ANY state is allowed as much roadspace as they require to safely maintain their bicycle...And possibly this is an international right as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_law Also, see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic

Comment: Walking quickly would be faster than regular walking. But is this really the type of question that is acceptable on this site? This is absolutely awful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may sound strange and childish, but I had a 1 mile walk to the subway every day over a bumpy tree-root-lifted sidewalk filled with other pedestrians, baby strollers, etc.

The street was busy and the space between parked cars and moving cars was a dedicated bike lane with a large number of bikers who yelled at skateboarders.  I was always frustrated I could not increase the length of time getting to the subway without generating a sweat in my clothes.

One day I saw a grown man skipping... like a kid in a playground... simply skipping to the subway. It is less then jogging, so it doesn't generate as much sweat and even with nice shoes you can do it.  Skipping doesn't require smooth sidewalks or a speed that can match or keep up with bikers.  It can also avoid other pedestrians, baby strollers etc.

The only issue is it's skipping and not the most manly mode of transportation.
I could never bring myself to do it, but it's an alternative that's faster and pretty adaptable to environments.

Comment: This solution is approved by Monte Python's flying circus.

Comment: I do skip around once in a while and can testify to its efficacy. It does wear you out, but not as much as jogging.

Comment: Using your legs to do the things they can do. Brilliant. [Boom. Life hack.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dYn-z8RoZg&feature=youtu.be)

Answer (score 4):

Roller blades/roller boots or simple skates. Wheely trainers if they come in adult sizes. Or one of those small push scooters (like the Ultrasport Kick Scooter available on Amazon), if you're allowed to use those on the sidewalks where you are. You can get electric versions of those scooters too.

Answer (score 4):

A longboard! It's the perfect mix between portability and speed. It looks like a skateboard, but the main goal is to "cruise" as smooth and fast as possible instead of performing tricks. They come in different size and shapes. In your case, I would suggest one with a low wheel-base for great stability since you aren't planning to do extreme things with it. A longboard seems difficult to ride, but the learning curve is really fast. Once you master the skills of long boarding, your life as a commuter will be more enjoyable!

Answer (score 2):

Each day going to work I have a journey that involves a mix of walking and taking trains, and there is one thing that I have noticed that appears to be on the rise in popularity and to me it does seem like a much better alternative to walking or cycling.

**Scooters for the commuters** (made up that name, but it has a nice ring to it).

They are neat looking, fold-able push scooters, not like those ones you see now-a-days at skate parks that the kids are riding, but one more suitable for the urban terrain.  They have large robust wheels and will help you get from A to B in no time at all, quicker, easier, and more fun than walking!

I haven't yet invested in one because I commute with other people. But these things do look fun and I might look into getting one in the future.

Here is a link to where you can buy some: [www.amazon.co.uk](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=commuter%20scooter&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Acommuter%20scooter) - some of them look childish, but amazon doesn't have great refining options so look around!

Comment: beat me to it, scooters are great ! durable, cheap(er than a bike), compact, and so hip :)

Answer (score 2):

I think a folding scooter is your best bet if you have a place to store it and if the pathway is relatively leveled (plain). If there are considerable ups and downs anything not motorized will suck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fitness walking aka walking in a faster pace than regular, let's say a step or two behind your jogging/running pace. It really works & you get to exercise as the same time.

Comment: And it does not require special gear and if done well you do not need a shower when coming in. (And seeing some joggers, you might be a bit faster than those.)